# Natty date time parser too many logs

Tags: java, natty

I am using natty date / time parser for parsing arbitrary formatted date / time string. It is producing too many logs:

> 016-08-24 18:22:22,821 INFO  [com.joestelmach.natty.Parser]
>   (pool-4-thread-1) AST: (DATE_TIME_ALTERNATIVE (DATE_TIME
>   (EXPLICIT_DATE (MONTH_OF_YEAR 8) (DAY_OF_MONTH 24) (DAY_OF_WEEK 4))
>   (EXPLICIT_TIME (HOURS_OF_DAY 18) (MINUTES_OF_HOUR 20)
>   (SECONDS_OF_MINUTE 14) America/New_York))) 2016-08-24 18:22:22,821
>   INFO  [com.joestelmach.natty.Parser] (pool-4-thread-1) STREAM:
>   WEDNESDAY WHITE_SPACE AUGUST WHITE_SPACE INT_24 WHITE_SPACE INT_18
>   COLON INT_36 COLON INT_24 WHITE_SPACE EST WHITE_SPACE INT_20 INT_16
>   2016-08-24 18:22:22,821 INFO  [com.joestelmach.natty.Parser]
>   (pool-4-thread-1) GROUP: WEDNESDAY WHITE_SPACE AUGUST WHITE_SPACE
>   INT_24 WHITE_SPACE INT_18 COLON INT_36 COLON INT_24 WHITE_SPACE EST
>   WHITE_SPACE INT_20 INT_16 2016-08-24 18:22:22,821 INFO 
>   [com.joestelmach.natty.Parser] (pool-4-thread-1) PARSE: WEDNESDAY
>   WHITE_SPACE AUGUST WHITE_SPACE INT_24 WHITE_SPACE INT_18 COLON INT_36
>   COLON INT_24 WHITE_SPACE EST WHITE_SPACE INT_20 INT_16 2016-08-24
>   18:22:22,821 INFO  [com.joestelmach.natty.Parser] (pool-4-thread-1)
>   AST: (DATE_TIME_ALTERNATIVE (DATE_TIME (EXPLICIT_DATE (MONTH_OF_YEAR
>   8) (DAY_OF_MONTH 24) (DAY_OF_WEEK 4)) (EXPLICIT_TIME (HOURS_OF_DAY 18)
>   (MINUTES_OF_HOUR 36) (SECONDS_OF_MINUTE 24) America/New_York)))

So I tried to stop it using

log4j.logger.com.joestelmach=ERROR

in both log4j.properties and log4j.xml.

Neither of this helped solve the problem.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: I was seeing the same issue and `log4j.logger.com.joestelmach.natty=WARN, CONSOLE` worked for me. I suspect your log4j configuration is broken in some other way.